# subsequent vowel checker in need of assistance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm finding it difficult to get the function to accept a value that returns True if the parameter contains 2 vowels right next to each other and False otherwise.

Here is what i have so far:

```py
def insert_sv_present(ch):
    lvowel = ['a' , 'e' , 'i','o' , 'u']
    uvowel = ['A', 'E' , 'I' , 'O', 'U']
    if(ch in lvowel) or (ch in uvowel):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: It seems that your function accepts a character rather than a complete string. Is that true?

Comment: It seems to me too but it makes no sense to check for 2 vowels if there's just 1 character... So I assumed it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the characters in your string and count how many vowels follows eachothers. If count is 2, two vowels are sequential.

As @S3DEV suggested the code will be cleaner like:

```
def insert_sv_present(ch):
    lvowel = ['a' , 'e' , 'i','o' , 'u']
    count = 0
    for c in ch:
        if c.lower() in lvowel:
            count += 1
            if count == 2:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
    return False
```

Comment: What about simplifying to: `if c.lower() in lvowel`?

Comment: That's of course an cleaner option but I prefer to not modify lines that are working, I'll add it anyway.

Comment: Fair play.  Conversely, often times we can use an answer to improve the existing code, and introduce beginners to better/best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ch` is a string and not a character, your check will only work if its size is `1`... You need to actually loop the string to find two consecutive characters.

Since the question asks for two ***consecutive*** vowels, we can use the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to loop the string `pairwise`:

```py
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def insert_sv_present(s):
    lvowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    for pair in pairwise(s):
        if pair[0].lower() in lvowel and pair[1].lower() in lvowel:
            return True
    return False
```

Which can then be a bit clarified and generalized by using the built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```py
def insert_sv_present(s):
    lvowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    for pair in pairwise(s):
        if all(ch.lower() in lvowel for ch in pair):
            return True
    return False
```

Which can even be further reduced using the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function, but that step might border with violating readability:

```py
def insert_sv_present(s):
    lvowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    return any(all(ch.lower() in lvowel for ch in pair) for pair in pairwise(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert_sv_present=lambda seq:True in [ch.lower() in 'aeiou' and seq[seq.index(ch.lower())+1].lower() in 'aeiou' for ch in seq[0:-1]]
```

this is the one-liner
hope it helped you!

***EDITED***
there is a little bit of optimization proposed by @Tomerikoo

```
insert_sv_present=lambda seq:True in [seq[i].lower() in 'aeiou' and seq[i+1].lower() in 'aeiou' for i in range(len(seq)-1)]
```

Comment: Why not loop on `range(len(seq)-1)` instead of calling `index` everytime?

Comment: @Tomerikoo cause anyway i would use extra code
in my case i used seq.index(ch) 
in your case i would add range and also seq[index] instead my ch

Comment: Yes but you realize that every call to `index` loops the list again and again? Instead just do `for i in range(len(seq)-1)` and replace `ch` with `seq[i]` and more importantly, replace `seq[seq.index(ch.lower())+1]` with a simple `seq[i+1]`...

Comment: Ok , i got it. But anyway the both solutions are good and works the same way .if thinking different , there is maybe an other solution that is better than my and your , just i proposed a solution that i found, not the best one

Comment: Sure. I Just offered a small optimization for ***your*** solution. I didn't say it was bad or compared it to any other possible solution